How can I disable unsafe-eval security feature to run my extension code at different webpages?

app.js?v=4.8.9.2:1 [Report Only] Refused to evaluate a string as
JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in
the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src data:
blob: 'self' 'report-sample' https://static.whatsapp.net
https://.youtube.com https://maps.googleapis.com
https://maps.gstatic.com https://.google-analytics.com
'wasm-unsafe-eval'".

I am facing an issue where I want to run my extension code on WhatsApp Web. I want to display a popup when clicking on my extension icon, which is created in the textarea field like the Grammarly icon. However, the popup is not working as expected. Please help me solve this problem. I am using V3 for creating the chrome extension..Thank you in advance.
